# App Center: Account is already associated with another identity provider

Tags: login, microsoft

I received an invitation to log in Microsoft App Center but when I try to log in with my existing Google or Github account, I see the error displayed in the screenshot.

I tried also to log in from an incognito window but it didn't solve the problem.

I saw some open questions in the community that were suggesting to click on the '?' icon to contact their customer support and ask them to fix the problem but I think that you can do it only if you are logged in (correct me if I'm wrong?).

If you can please help me solving this problem or at least tell me how to contact the App Center customer support without being logged in.

[image]

PS: I am using Google Chrome 112.0.5615.121 from Mac os X Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: It'd seem like there's an SSO with Microsoft but they refuse, since that identity is already in-use. Just ask the support to fix whatever need fixing and then it'll work. As already said - you should be able to login to github and contact support without logging in to MS AC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the error page is interesting :

> Account with this email is already associated With another identity provider: github

Your case is perhaps the same as in
[this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/840057/app-center-log-in-failed?orderby=helpful),
where an old github account used the same email as yours.

In any case, you don't need to login in order to request help
from the
[GitHub Support page](https://support.github.com/request).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is taken care by Github, because Microsoft App Center is owned by Microsoft, right? But I tried to open a ticket and explain the situation. Hopefully they will be able to help.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem but at least you pointed out how to get some support. A developer answered that he is working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the *"invitation to log in"* is not a *"register yourself at"* link that tries to create a new account?

In this case it is logical, that entering your already registered e-mail will generate the shown error.

My first try (after checking the link that it may be trusted) would be

1. Try to [sign in at the Microsoft App Center](https://appcenter.ms/sign-in) using your Open-ID of GitHub.
2. If there is not yet an account at the "Microsoft App Center" you will be redirected to "Choose your username to start", so creating the App Center account. It's finished after you've added your first app or added an organisation.
3. When logged in test you invitation link.

If it is not a *"register yourself at"* link, the expectation is that you are logged in when clicking the link. The automatically triggered "sign in" process interrupts your walk to the destination.

Comment: Did the answer solve your question? If not: What have been the results trying this?

Comment: I can't even log in through the Microsoft App Center. I get the same error: "Oops, something went wrong" 

Comment: What did you do in the meantime? At the MS AppCenter: (1) Did you already have an account? If no: (2) Did you successfully finish the sign-in procedure (so creating an account)? (3) Did you use your GitHub credentials or others? (4) The statement *"I can't even login through the MS App Center"* is your try log login *WITHOUT* the invitation,  just using the login screen? (5) Do you have installed any browser-plugins? Some may interfere. => Please create a second browser profile and use the default-settings (which browser? For me it worked fine using Firefox ) — Thanks for updating the state.